# Registering a fileextension in visual studio to a build-action

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, appharbor

I have .tmpl-files in my solution used to store jQuery-templates, and in order for my project to run on AppHarbor I need to set the Build Action for every one of those files to "Content". Is there any way that I can make VS recognize .tmpl-files and per default set them to "Content"? I don't care much if I need to set all my existing ones to "Content" manually, though I foresee that I'll forget to do so when I create new files in the feature, that's why I'd like VS to do that for me based on the files I create. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx